# Need examples of web server software(Apart from apache)

Tags: web-server

everyone. I am trying to find out about web server software other than Apache, but unfortunately,there seems to be a lack of information on this topic. Could somebody please give me some examples or refer me to some? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A lack of information???? not at all, just use wikipedia or google for heavens sake.

Start [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) and look at the comparison links at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

lighthttpd on Linux and IIS on Windows.

This should help lots hopefully: [Web Server Survey](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/category/web-server-survey/)